# Using Amazon (Product Advertising) API disable join button

Tags: api, join, amazon-product-advertising-api

I signed up as an associate to use the API, but then when clicking the Product Advertising API, it did not let me sign up. I emailed to see how I can access it and was told this:

> Registration for the Product Advertising API is only available to Associates that have been reviewed and received final acceptance in to the Associates Program.
>
> Applications that are in the pending approval status will be reviewed once 3 referrals are made on the application.

I don't know what that really means, and I don't even necessarily want to be an associate; I just want to use this API to get Amazon search results for a browser extension. Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

They added a new rule recently ! You can only use the Product API if you have sold at least 3 items.
I've tried to do this with a different account and credit card, but I still got 0% commission lol

and then you need to contact to amazon